# Pass a column as parameter to dateadd in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameter-passing, dateadd

I want to convert a column of UTC time to local time.

My data looks like this:

```
time_utc                TZID            timezone
------------------------------------------------
2014-02-27 12:00:39.0   America/Toronto     -5
2013-05-21 09:35:30.0   America/Goose_Bay   -4
2015-01-08 06:58:58.0   America/Creston     -7
```

I know that using

```
select *, DATEADD(hour, 5,time_utc)
from mytable
```

will add 5 hours to column `time_utc`.

However, as you can see, I have a variable time zone column.

How can I pass this variable to the `dateadd` function?

I tried the following 2 commands but they don't work:

Attempt #1:

```
select *, DATEADD(hour, timezone, time_utc)
from mytable
```

Attempt #2:

```
select *, DATEADD(hour, (select timezone from mytable), time_utc)
from mytable
```

Both throws this error:

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function. [SQL State=S0001, DB Errorcode=8116]

For decimal values of timezone, for instance -3.5, how would this work?

Thanks

Comment: Consider changing the datatype of `timezone` as it seems to be `varchar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass this variable to datetime function?

Just reference the column in the function call:

```
select *, DATEADD(hour, timezone, time_utc)
from mytable
```

> For decimal values of timezone, for instance -3.5, how would this work?

The "number" parameter of `DATEADD` takes an integer, so you'd have to change to minutes and scale the hour offset.  Since your `timezone` colume is apparently a varchar column, convert it to a decimal value as well:

```
select *, DATEADD(minute, cast(timezone as decimal(4,2)) * 60 , time_utc)
from mytable
```

Comment: I tried this first. It gives me the following error:
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function. [SQL State=S0001, DB Errorcode=8116] @d_stanley

Comment: @AsiehHarati That's important information to know.  I've added one function you can use to convert text to numeric data.

Comment: Thank you D Stanley. Yes, this works! Just a question. As I understand, the biggest time zone difference is 30 minutes (0.5) and so time zone ranges are  from -12.0 to 12.0 with only one decimal digit (0 or 5). In that case, we can change decimal(4,2) to decimal(3,1) since, when multiplied by 60, it will be a natural not decimal number.

Comment: @AsiehHarati Sure - it won't make any real difference if none of your data has more than one decimal digit.  `DATEADD` will truncate it to an integer anyways.

Answer (score 1):

There is a character value (most probably blank) in your dataset. Sql does implicity conversion but for non numeric value it will fail. Check your table to see if you have blanks or non numeric values for timezone