# DATEADD in SQL where the second parameter is the result of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I should use `DATEADD` in SQL.

I know that the syntax is, for example `DATEADD (SECOND, 10, GETUTCDATE())`, but I need the second parameter be configurable. In other words, that 10 number os seconds must be the result of a query. Is that possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a column as parameter to dateadd in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732183/pass-a-column-as-parameter-to-dateadd-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You just use a subquery.  In this context, such a subquery is called a *scalar subquery*, meaning that it can return at most one row and exactly one column.  For instance:

```
select dateadd(second,
               (select sum(seconds) from t where col = 'x'),
               getutcdate()
              )
```

In general, such a query can usually be rewritten without a subquery.  However, a subquery is often a fine approach.

Comment: Another possible use: `select dateadd(second,
               tableOfSeconds.secondsToAdd, getutcdate()) from tableOfSeconds where col = @whatSeconds`